# Expanding the size of an Android Virtual Device (emulator) instance?

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

On a relatively new emulator image (AVD) I have about 40mb of free space. How can I expand this?

**UPDATE:**
Just to be clear... I'm talking about the "Internal phone storage" size, not the SD Card size.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Your goal is to use as little space as possible. It's a phone.

Comment: Who said I was developing for a phone?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think:

```
$ emulator -partition-size <number of megabytes>
```

is what you're looking for.  I tried a few different values in the emulator and the "internal phone storage" setting seemed to reflect the values I passed in.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why this isn't listed in the online docs at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#startup-options

Comment: also size is in MB, so if you do  500, you will get a 500MB internal storage.

Comment: Can I set this parameter in the device config file?

Answer (score -2):

If you're talking about the SD card size, I believe you'll need to make a new SD card file of a larger file, then load your AVD using the new SD card you've created.  They have instructions on how to create an SD card (and load it into an AVD) here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#creatingm

Essentially, make the SD card:

```
$ mksdcard <size> <file>
```

Then load it into your emulator using the `-sdcard` argument:

```
$ emulator -sdcard <filepath>
```

Comment: No... the "Internal phone storage" size.