# MonoDroid: Running out of space on fresh Virtual Device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, mono, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I have begun evaluating MonoDroid. (I've built many apps using Android+Eclipse)

I created  new-from-template Android app using MonoDevelop on a Mac. I started up a new Virtual Device with 250 megs. API level 15.

The error I get is that MonoDroid can't install the runtime as there isn't enough space.

See image below:
[image]

Comment: You've set 250MB for the virtual SD card, not the `/data` partition.

Comment: Possibly related: [Expanding the size of an Android Virtual Device (emulator) instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923526/expanding-the-size-of-an-android-virtual-device-emulator-instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin recommends starting the emulator with a partition-size of 512MB in order to have enough room for the installation. If you start the emulator from within MonoDevelop or Visual Studio, it will actually do this automatically. If you're starting the emulator yourself, you need to do something like:

```
.\emulator -avd NameOfYourEmulator -partition-size 512
```

More details can be found in their documentation [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/command_line_emulator).

Comment: Hi Greg, We tried adding a new emulator with 512 megs, but got the same error. "No Space Left on Device"

Comment: What are you setting to 512MB? Your screenshot shows you setting the SD card which is not what you want here. Do you still have this problem when you let MonoDevelop start the emulator for you?

Comment: MonoDevelop/Mac often won't start the emulator. I'll try a full reboot and everything off and see if that works.